# access text in ASP.NET server control declaration

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

If a server control was declared like this

```
<my:customControl id="cc1" runat="server">
  Help me obi-wan kenobi!
</my:customControl>
```

is it possible to access the text between the tags?

Answer (score 0):

If asp.net know how to parse your control (reflect Literal, LiteralControl, TextBox controls to see how its done)

```
[ControlBuilder(typeof(YourControlBuilder)), DefaultProperty("Text")] 
public class YourControl : Control, ITextControl {

}
[Bindable(true), DefaultValue(""), Localizable(true)]
public string Text {
    get;
    set;
}
public class YourControlBuilder : ControlBuilder {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `[ParseChildren(true, "Text")]` to your custom control class will do this.

You can find more information along with samples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.aspx

**EDIT**

Relevant snippet from the above link

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Employees")]
```

> Use the ParseChildren attribute to set
>   the ChildrenAsProperties and
>   DefaultProperty properties. Using this
>   constructor, the control parses all
>   child controls as properties and must
>   define a public property named
>   Employees, which it declares as an
>   ArrayList. Nested (child) elements
>   must correspond to child elements of
>   the Employees property or to other
>   properties of the control.